# Using \bm only bolds parts of the equation

Tags: math-mode

```
\bm{{\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}=}}
```

When I try to bold a part of the equation using `\bm` it only bolds the `\mathrm{d}` part. Is there a solution to this?

[image]

I've tried to use `\boldsymbol` but it gives the same output. I've also tried `\pmb`, which gave me a good result if not for the shadows left behind the symbols.[image]

When I try using `\mathbf` I don't get the bolded text in the same font and instead get this result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        bindingoffset=0mm,
        left=8mm,
        right=8mm,
        top=8mm,
        bottom=12mm,
        footskip=4mm]
        {geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \mathbf{{\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}=}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile to reproduce what you show. Right now, we have no idea which font setup you're using of which tools for maths.  You have not even told us which format you're using: LaTeX? plain? ConTeXt?

Comment: `unicode-math` should be loaded **after** all other maths and font packages. (And it will load `amsmath` if it hasn't already been loaded.) If you don't want to use `unicode-math`, don't load it; if you do, don't fight it ;).

Comment: Even after changing the order of loading I still can't get it to produce good results. Any other tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The bm package doesn't work with unicode-math. But beside this, why do want to make a complete equation bold? That's rather unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make an entire expression bold, you should use `\boldmath` outside the math.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0mm,
            left=8mm,
            right=8mm,
            top=8mm,
            bottom=12mm,
            footskip=4mm]
            {geometry}


    \usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version=bold,FakeBold=2]{Latin Modern Math}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{gather*}
        \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}
    \end{gather*}

\boldmath
    \begin{gather*}
        \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Latin Modern Math does not come with a bold font (which is why `\bm` does not work) but you can use a FakeBold version, as shown.

Answer (score 4):

The [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package provides the commands `\symbf` and `\symbfit`, which should be used instead of `\mathbf` and `\bm`. See Table 7 in the user manual of the `unicode-math` package for a complete listing of available `\symxx` and `\symxxxx` commands.

If you want bold math letters and symbols to be rendered in *italics*, be sure to load the `unicode-math` package with the option `bold-version=ISO`. To render the diff operator with an upright bold letter **d**, be sure to write `\symbfup{d}`.

I think it would be most unusual, and it would likely hurt overall legibility, to embolden the integral, square-root, and binary and relational operator (such as `+`, `-`, and `=`) symbols.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex %% or "lualatex"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[
       \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x }{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\ne
\symbf{\int\frac{\symbfup{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using \mathbf instead of \pmb:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        bindingoffset=0mm,
        left=8mm,
        right=8mm,
        top=8mm,
        bottom=12mm,
        footskip=4mm]
        {geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \mathbf{{\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}=}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The loading order is wrong. See `unicode-math`'s manual section 3. If I compile your code, only the `x` looks bold. (Even if I correct the order.)